# jQuery Datatables resume after AJAX call completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the Datatables plugin for jQuery, and I am trying to figure out how to resume the script once the AJAX call was successfull.

My current code is:

```
var table = $("#dataTables-example").DataTable(
        {
            ajax: {
                url: "/kleurmixer/hmi/view_json2.php?type=2",
                dataSrc: '',
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 7 ] },
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8 ] }
            ]
        }
);
```

Now, in Chrome and FF it works. But since this is a page made for WinCC (which uses IE7), it doesn't work. So I need some kind of callback function for my AJAX call, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: It does not work in IE7 because of the trailing comma `dataSrc: '',`←

Comment: After removing that comma, it still doesn't work. It still says Loading...

Comment: also after refreshing with ctrl-F5 (I believe it is)? Trailing commas is a IE7 killer :(

Comment: I am using WinCC because it is used to control hardware which makes it a bit harder (there is no Ctrl + F5). Even when I completely restart the program it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a callback for `done` or `success` like this. You could also add `error` and `statusCode` if you need that.

```
var table = $("#dataTables-example").DataTable(
    {
        ajax: {
            url: "/kleurmixer/hmi/view_json2.php?type=2",
            dataSrc: '',
            "done": function(){
                alert('done');
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 7 ] },
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8 ] }
        ]
    }
);
```

Update 1: Another datatable approach

```
$("#dataTables-example").dataTable( {
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
      alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
    }
} );
```

[Documentation for Datatables initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding that doesn't alert me done, even though the table was loaded properly (In Chrome).

Comment: Try and add success, error and statusCode to get more info then. Maybe you can spot something in developer Tools also on the request

Comment: IE7 doesn't have these kind of tools. Adding success with a alert in it, doesn't work either because it returns me the alert before actually loading the table.

Comment: What about my update1? Can you fix it by listen to the events Datatables fires? :)

Comment: That doesn't work either (in IE7). In Chrome it once again outputs everything just fine, in IE7 it doesn't alert anything at all.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to do then because I don't work with IE7. Here is a compability table in case it can give you anything. I hope you figured it out. 
https://www.datatables.net/download/compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways. I really have no way of debugging it either. Since it is showed in WinCC which makes it way harder to debug aswell.

Comment: I worked out what part of the problem is. If I add an alert after I create my table, it does work just fine. After a bit of googling that is because AJAX is Asynchronous and the alert provides just enough delay for it to wait for the AJAX response and put it in the table. Do you happen to know any work around?